# Cell value displays as 1. Formula doesn't recognize value as one

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell that is filled by the following formula:

`=IF(AND((ISBLANK(E260)), (ISBLANK(G260)))=TRUE,"",(IF(ISBLANK(I260)=TRUE,"",SUM(K259,I260))))`
This cell shows a value of one.

I am using the following conditional formatting to make this cell have bold text and green fill:`=AND((ISBLANK(I10)),(K9=1))` (Those are the reference cells).

However, the formula doesn't recoginze the cell as being = to 1. It seems to act as if the cell is not equal to 1. I would be grateful if someone could explain what I am doing wrong. Relevant snapshots are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `K259` = 0.997927296
- `I260` = 0.00207270
- `K259 + I260` = 0.999999996, not 1. You can show more decimal places to verify this. The number format or display is not the same as the underlying number.

You might consider adding a `ROUND` in your conditional formatting to get around this, if needed.

Comment: Yup. Everything in that column was formatted to show eight decimal places. I added round to my conditional formatting as you suggested:                  
=AND((ISBLANK(I10)),((ROUND(K9,8))=1))         Thank you for politely pointing out what should have been obvious to me. :-)  What makes it more embarrassing is I even have a column to tell me which numbers have been rounded up or down, but didn't think to apply that knowledge to the running total. Smh.

Comment: Ah no problem - it's the weekend so we all get a pass :-)